# How to apply Reverse STUFF in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a string value with space and I want to devide it with my case like

'Hello John Smith' and here I want in while loop as below

```
Hello John Smith
Hello John
Hello
```

I have used `STUFF`:

```
declare @SearchName varchar(50) = 'Hello John Smith'

while len(@SearchName) > 0          
begin 
    select @SearchName

    set @SearchName = replace(@SearchName,'  ',' ')       
    set @SearchName = replace(@SearchName,'  ',' ')               
    set @SearchName = stuff(@SearchName, 1, charindex(' ', @SearchName+' '), '')   
END
```

But here I am getting output as below:

```
Hello John Smith
John Smith
Smith
```

Can you please give me a solution for this?

Comment: so you just want to split it?

Comment: ya want to split but not like Hello , John , Smith..  want 'Hello John Smith', 'Hello John', 'Hello'

Comment: Loops are much more inefficient than set based approaches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not super optimized solution, but it is just from top of my head. Just reverse your string and you will get what you want:

```
DECLARE @SearchName VARCHAR(50) = REVERSE('Hello John Smith')
WHILE LEN(@SearchName) > 0
    BEGIN 
        SELECT REVERSE(@SearchName)
        SET @SearchName = REPLACE(@SearchName, '  ', ' ')       
        SET @SearchName = REPLACE(@SearchName, '  ', ' ')    

        SET @SearchName = STUFF(@SearchName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @SearchName + ' '), '')
    END
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Using tally to split. Not a fan of loops:

```
DECLARE @SearchName varchar(50) = 'Hello John Smith'

;WITH 
N(N)AS 
(SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)),
tally(N)AS(SELECT TOP (LEN(@SearchName) + 1) 
 ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d,N e,N fm)
SELECT LEFT(@SearchName, N - 1) FROM tally
WHERE substring(@SearchName +' ', N, 1) = ' '
ORDER BY N DESC
```

Result:

```
Hello John Smith
Hello John
Hello
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. its usable for me. Actually i want loop just because i have to do operation on each word. for example if we consider above string then i have to search records from table with following words 'Hello John Smith', 'Hello John', 'Hello' , 'John' , 'Smith'.

Answer (score 1):

Usually better to avoid loops:

- Here I use a recursive CTE to get the position of each space.
- I then only have to get the left part of the string up until each space position.

**Query:**

```
declare @SearchName varchar(50) = 'Hello John Smith';

with cte as (
    SELECT id = 0, p = CHARINDEX(' ', @SearchName)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id+1, p = CHARINDEX(' ', @SearchName, p+1) FROM cte
    WHERE p > 0

)
SELECT * FROM your table d
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [string] = CASE WHEN p=0 THEN @SearchName
        ELSE LEFT(@SearchName, p-1) END
    FROM cte
) c ON d.[yourvalue] LIKE '%'+c.string+'%'
;
```

**Output:**

```
Hello John Smith
Hello John
Hello
```

A LIKE with '%' at the beginning will not be efficient on a big table because I cannot use the index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. its usable for me.but  i want to use in while loop. for each string i have to do operation.

Comment: are your string in a table or in variables?

Comment: its a dynamic variable.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. what is your dynamic variable?

Comment: string is passed from front-end and have to search records from table for each word in string for example if we consider above string then i have to search records from table with following words 'Hello John Smith', 'Hello John', 'Hello' , 'John' , 'Smith'. hope you understand now.

Comment: see my update. this type of seach with '%' at the beginning is not efficient on big tables